# A method in java named charAt() is not working?

Tags: java

There is a method in java charAt() is not working on my program is not working . I have google it and found that it may lies in a package named java.lang.String;. But its still not working . If you have any solution then please help me . I am attaching my code to notice where is the problem ..
Hope , you can help me out ...

Here is my code

```
/*
package default;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

public class Cryptography { //Starting of the class Cryptography 

    /*The initialization  of the variables */

    private int i;

    private int UserChoice;

    private String  UserValue;

    private  char []  Word;

    private char Blank;

    private char IncrementedWord;

    private int EncryptedWord;

    /*The initialization of the variables */


    Scanner GetValue = new Scanner(System.in);

     public void UserPassword() { // Starting of the function UserPassword 

        System.out.println("Enter your password :: ");

        UserValue = GetValue.nextLine();


    } //End of the function UserPassword


    public void EnCryption() {  // Starting of the function Encryption

        Word = new char[ UserValue.toCharArray().length + 100 ];

        Blank = '\0';

        Word = /*Blank + */ UserValue.toCharArray();



        for( i = 0; i < Word.length; i++ ){

            if(Character.isUpperCase(Word.charAt(i))){

                char Charecter = (char)((int)Word)

            }
        }

    }  //End of the function Encryption 

    public void DeCryption() {}



    public void UserChoice() { //Starting of the function UserChoice 

        System.out.println("Enter 1 for EnCryption .. ");
        System.out.println("Enter 2 for DeCryption .. ");

        UserChoice = GetValue.nextInt();

        switch( UserChoice ) { // Starting of the switch case

            case 1: { // Starting of the case 1  

                EnCryption();

                break; 

            } case 2 : { //Starting of the case 2 

                DeCryption();

                break;

            } default : { //Starting of the default 

                System.out.println(" Invalid Choice ");

            } // End of the defalut 


        } // End of the switch case 

    } // End of the function UserChoice


} //End of the class Cryptography

*/
```

Comment: I strongly recommend working through some basic Java tutorials. `String` isnot a package, it's a class *in* a package (the package is `java.lang`). `char[]` is not a `String`. I'd also strongly recommend using [standard Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). Instance members should start with a lower case letter, not a capital letter. E.g., `word`, not `Word`. Finally: Although it's not *required*, I suggest using `this.` on instance members for clarity. (This last is a matter of style.)

Comment: And `java.lang` is imported automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Word` instance member is a `char[]`, not a `String`. They are two very different things. From [the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.9):

> In the Java programming language, unlike C, an array of `char` is not a `String`, and neither a `String` nor an array of `char` is terminated by `'\u0000'` (the NUL character).
>
> A `String` object is immutable, that is, its contents never change, while an array of `char` has mutable elements.

To access the `char` at index `i` in a `char[]` called `Word`, use `Word[i]`.